# Flash png has native width and height but is scaled

Tags: flash-cs5, scale

i'm a flash beginner! When i import a png to the lib and add it to a movieclip, it has the origin width and height when i check the properties ... but it looks definitly scaled!

Why?
How can i make it have the origin width and height?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why it looks scaled? Is it blurred or what?

Comment: but in the properties the width and height are the correct origin values of the native png ...

Comment: where can i set the pixel ratio ... ?

i just discovered somthing helpful ... when i drag the image from the lib to the stage it keeps the correct ratio ... if i drag it to the movieclip its squeezed ...

Comment: Then the instance of the MovieClip where you drag it onto is scaled itself! Try to open the MovieClip from the library and check if it is correct then. (Pixel ratio can be set in i.e. Photoshop, but its not the point I think)

Answer (score 1):

ok, i deleted the movieclip, made a new one and inserted the png again and now it has the right ratio ...